# bizdays function returning incorrect values when start & end dates are nonworking days

Tags: r, date

I need to calculate the number of workdays in between two dates. I have a custom calendar set up to account for holidays within my organization. The bizdays function seems to return the wrong value - for example:

```
> library(bizdays)
> library(lubridate)
> bizdays(ymd('2017-06-12'), ymd('2017-06-16'))
[1] 4
```

(When in fact, this should return 5 because I'm asking how many days are between Monday and Friday of this week.) However, it's not as simple as just adding a workday whenever I use this function. The output further varies depending on if the start/end dates are weekends, or holidays in my calendar. If it is helpful I can post the various permutations (start date as weekend, end as weekday; etc etc.) Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so what is the pattern to how bizdays works?

Comment: This should return 16 - 12 = 4 (or three if there's a holiday that week)

Comment: how many numbers are between 4 and 10 --> 10 - 4 + 1 = 7 @lebelinoz

Comment: @Masoud It looks like bizdays is not inclusive of both end days

Comment: @lebelinoz @Masoud I don't think it's as simple as a 16 - 12 = 4. For example: 
`> bizdays(ymd('2017-06-12'), ymd('2017-06-17'))
[1] 4
> bizdays(ymd('2017-06-11'), ymd('2017-06-17'))
[1] 5
> bizdays(ymd('2017-05-29'), ymd('2017-06-17'))
[1] 14` (included May 29 for reference - it's a holiday - and in that case correctly calculating the # of workdays. not sure if it's b/c it's recognizing it as a holiday, or doing the same calculation as in my original post)